# KVO do these do the exact same thing?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

Do these do the same thing, if not what exactly is the difference?

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"user.name" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:SomeContext];
```

and

```
[self.user addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:SomeContext];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do slightly different things. The former observes the key path `"user.name"` on `self` meaning that it will trigger if either `user` or that user's `name` changes. The latter observes `"name"` on `self.user` meaning that it will only trigger if `name` of that user changes.

Comment: Ok so if `self.user` was later changed the second example would be broken and probably lead to a crash when self gets deallocated?

Comment: If `self.user` was changes in the second example it would still be observing the previous user instance. If that instance was deallocated it would assert/crash. If the new user instance changes its name it would not trigger the observation.